# Determine date ranges based on groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

Need help in writing the Sql query for the below format:

Source Data:

```
Field1    Field2  last_update
1234      ABC     2013-01-01
1234      ABC     2013-01-02
1234      ABC     2013-01-03
1234      ABC     2013-01-06
2345      ABC     2013-01-07   -- Field1 is different from prev. row, new group
2345      ABC     2013-01-08
2345      ABC     2013-01-09
1234      ABC     2013-01-10   -- Field1 is different from prev. row, new group
1234      ABC     2013-01-11
2345      ABC     2013-01-12   -- Field1 is different from prev. row, new group
```

Result set data should be in the below format:

```
Field1  Field2  start_date  stop_date
1234    ABC     2013-01-01  2013-01-06
2345    ABC     2013-01-07  2013-01-09
1234    ABC     2013-01-10  2013-01-11
2345    ABC     2013-01-12  2013-01-12
```

The logic to produce the result is based on `last_update`: `start_date` is `min(last_update)` of that group and `stop_date` is `max(last_update)`. If `Field1` is different from previous row then a different grouping starts.

Comment: how are you determining the split between different groupings of duplicate field1/field2 combinations?

Comment: based on last_update from source --- start_date is min(last_update) of that group and stopdate is max(last_update). If i see the field 1 is varying from previous row then i should consider that set as different grouping.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @ssab Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you want to find contiguous sequences in your data. This is usually referred to as a *gaps-and-islands* problem and one solution is to use the`row_number()`function to determine groups (islands) like this:

```
SELECT 
    Field1, 
    Field2, 
    Start_date = MIN(last_update),
    Stop_date = MAX(last_update)
FROM (
    SELECT 
       Field1, Field2, last_update,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY last_update) -
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Field1, Field2 ORDER BY last_update) grp
    FROM [Source Data]
    ) A
GROUP BY Field1, Field2, grp
ORDER BY MIN(last_update)
```

With your sample data this would be the result:

```
Field1      Field2 Start_date Stop_date
----------- ------ ---------- ----------
1234        ABC    2013-01-01 2013-01-06
2345        ABC    2013-01-07 2013-01-09
1234        ABC    2013-01-10 2013-01-11
2345        ABC    2013-01-12 2013-01-12
```

The solution comes from a book in the *SQL Server MVP Deep Dives* series, but I can't remember which one and who to credit.

Comment: impressive! Maybe one day i'll be able to grasp row_number/over/partition and whatnot to that degree  :D

Comment: The solution comes from a book in the series _SQL Server MVP Deep Dives_ that I highly recommend if you want to dig deeper :) Can't remember which volume it's from though.